# JavaScript isn't working in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

JavaScript isn't working in ruby on rails. I have included my JavaScript in the assets file and in the application.js with `//=require_tree .`.

the code of the javascript i am trying to run:
$( document ).ready(function() {

```
$('#nav > div').hover(
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('img').stop().animate({
            'width'     :'199px',
            'height'    :'199px',
            'top'       :'-25px',
            'left'      :'-25px',
            'opacity'   :'1.0'
        },500,'easeOutBack',function(){
            $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(700);
        });

        $this.find('a:first,h2').addClass('active');
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('ul').fadeOut(500);
        $this.find('img').stop().animate({
            'width'     :'52px',
            'height'    :'52px',
            'top'       :'0px',
            'left'      :'0px',
            'opacity'   :'0.1'
        },5000,'easeOutBack');

        $this.find('a:first,h2').removeClass('active');
    }
);
```

});

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide detailed information about your case. Including the code example would be nice as well.

Comment: in the application layout i have used javascript_include_tag and added the application.js in which it requires the tree....but it is not loading.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>WebApp</title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', media:'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are executing your javascript when the document is ready, like this (assuming you are using JQuery and Coffeescript):

```
$ -> # do you have this?
  alert 'test'
```

Also check your browser's console for any errors.

**UPDATE**

Try to replace your code with this and see which alerts are showing...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(1)

    $('body').hover(
       function () {
         alert(2)
       }
    )

    $('#nav > div').hover(
       function () {
         alert(3)
       }
    )
})
```

Comment: I did this...and i got the alert but the javascript isn't really doing anything

Comment: @suhabaobeid please, update your question with the javascript code you are trying to run

Comment: @devochka-volshebnita all alerts appeared...i am confused

Comment: @suhabaobeid so the problem is with your animation. try to remove this `easeOutBack` argument. if that doesn't work then try to apply your animation to `$this` instead of the `img` (`$this.animate({ ....`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've given. You can try to check this/these:

**Make sure your included javascript files are before the ending:**

*//= require_tree .*

An example is this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Depending on your setup you might want to precompile those assets in which case it might be useful to edit **config>initializers>assets.rb**

An example should be included in the file, just make a new line and replace it with your javascript filename.

*As always, see the documentation here as it might help figure out your issue:*

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: yes it is like that...sorry there was a typo in the question..i edited it

Answer (score 0):

When javascript isn't working I ask myself a couple questions.

Is jQuery loading correctly? Open up chrome console, can you type `$` hit enter and not receive an error? If you receive something like the following code, jQuery is working.

```
// console test
$
=> jQuery(selector, context)
```

Then you've got javascript working. But most of the time, I run into an error because I'm not telling javascript to wait until the document is done loading because I've forgotten the following lines of code.

```
// regular jquery / javascript
$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert("This javascript thing is reals making me mad!");
});
```

Here's the same thing in Coffeescript

```
# Coffeescript
$(document).ready ->
  alert 'This javascript thing is reals making me mad!'
  return
```

If you receive alerts, then your javascript is working! However, the last question I might ask is, is my javascript file in the correct folder?
Be sure to place your `.js` file withing the `app/assets/javascripts/` folder. Then it will be loaded within the assetpipeline.

Comment: I actually did all the suggested and I did get the alert, I made the javascript to wait. I don't know what i am missing.....can i plz send u the code to check ? It is not much

Comment: Sure, you can send me the code and I'll check it. I'd say your JavaScript is working, but the JavaScript code you've written is not doing what you expect. You

Comment: how can i send it to u ? u prefer email or anything else? I can't post the whole code here...thnx

Comment: I'd upload it to github.com as a public repository. Then I can download it to my computer and test it out.

Comment: hey, you've still got to add the code into it. When I go there, it shows it as empty.